# How to get multiple values from a function?

Tags: c, function, return

So i have this code here, it should read multiple numbers until the user types one between 0 and 10.

```
int i_want_to_return_those(){
int x,z,y;
do{
scanf("%d", &x);
getchar();
}while (x < 0 || x > 10);

do{
scanf("%i", &y);
getchar();
}while (x < 0 || x > 10);



do{
scanf("%i", &z);
getchar();
}while (z < 0 || z > 10);


return???;

}
```

I want to return x, y and z. but i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: You either return a structure or pass pointers to the return values into the function.

Comment: May I suggest that you make use of your favourite search engine to do basic research before posting a question? For many questions you are likely to find an existing answer (on this site or elsewhere) in less time than it takes to post the question.